# Recover lost file in Android Studio

Tags: android

My computer crashed while I was working on the project.

My mainActivity.java has no code inside there now.

I have tried going to

I:\Users\myUsername.AndroidStudio2.1\system\LocalHistory but I don't see the file there.

Answer (score 0):

Open MainActivity.java in Android Studio, right click inside the file and go for LocalHisoty > Show History. Let me know if it works, please. Cheers

Comment: @Tried but nothing is there

Answer (score 0):

You can use your last debug version of application and decode it,you can find it in \app\build\outputs\apk folder

Comment: I have since started coding it back. It's not a huge amount of code thankfully. Anyway decoding the APK will result in different variables naming I suppose?

Comment: No I don't think.but it's a little hard to decode if use progurd or else and in that case you maybe see different variable naming.
if it help you accept my answer,i lost my previous account and all of my badge:)